# .htaccess doesn't redirect url and i cant use $_GET['']

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello I've got a site that uses php and mvc and I've got a link http://localhost/kipsalahome/post?title=Title-of-the-news-2&lang=En that I want to convert into http://localhost/kipsalahome/post/Title-of-the-news-2/En and still be able to use $_GET[''] I'm using this code in htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 

# Remove php extensions from a file extension

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z]+) post.php?title=$1&lang=$2 [QSA,NC,L]


# Hide local file structure
Options -Indexes
```

but sadly it does nothing for me. I would like to know what i'm doing wrong and how could i fix it.

Comment: the url needs to be in the url param format like this (http://localhost/kipsalahome/post?title=Title-of-the-news-2&lang=En) in order for you to use $_GET to access title or lang

Comment: If you are using an MVC architecture, then you know that you should parse all requests through a single file, like `index.php`, right? I say this, because I have the feeling that you want to apply multiple `RewriteRule`s similar to your last one. E.g. to apply the routing functionality inside `.htaccess`. If this is what you intend to do, then don't do it!

Comment: Use a router, like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), in order to apply routing inside the apllication's entry point (in `index.php` or similar). It will give you a lot of possibilities. Your url could then very much look like this, if you wish: `http://john:doe@localhost:458/Title-of-the-news-2/En?v1=1234&v2=abcdef#asdf`. This is the format of a complete URI, as defined in the official [URI: Generic Syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) specification. If you decide to follow my advice, then `.htaccess` will be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need the rule as below:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*) post.php?title=$1&lang=$2
```

Refer: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 0):

in my test the above htacesss worked correctly:

URL: http://server/test**/post/Title-of-the-news-2/En**

post.php -> print_r($_GET);

resultado: **Array ( [title] => Title-of-the-news-2 [lang] => En )**

---

To use more parameters in the url do so:

URL http://server/teste/post/Title-of-the-news-2/En?sandbox=true

post.php -> print_r($_GET);

resultado: **Array ( [title] => Title-of-the-news-2 [lang] => En [sandbox] => true )**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answers i'll look through them all, but i found temporary solution by creating my link that way `<?php $link = URLROOT. "post/" .$newsVal->Blog_Title_En.'/'` and then exploding it on other page to get needed variables.